# Hanging roller shades in a shallow window

Tags: windows, hanging

I am purchasing solar roller shades for two large windows in my apartment's living room.  One window is deep and doesn't pose a problem for inside mount (my strong preference!) The other is very shallow. Only 1/2" deep.  I was wondering if attaching the brackets to the side of the window frame as pictured with only two screws would be strong enough to hold a shade for a 94"W x 66'L window. [image: bracket position]

Comment: Are you asking about screws going into the green window frame, or into the beige wall board?

Comment: The wall.  They cannot go into the window frame.

Comment: You have no meat on that wall to screw in. There is a 1/2 inch dry wall which would not hold anything.

Answer (score 1):

This wall appears to be finished with some kind of drywall wallboard. It is a layer likely 1/2" thick across the entire surface of the wall. There at the edge of your window you have access only to the end of the drywall, not to any wood structure behind it.

There are anchors available that can be used to hang a surprising amount of weight on drywall but there's a caveat. They need to be some distance away from an edge and they would never work going into the drywall in the way contemplated here.

Just about any window covering for this window will have to mount to the face of the wall. Exactly where wood structure will be found varies, but a good place to try setting screws is about 1.25" to the sides of the window or 1.25-1.75" above it.

Comment: Thank you!  If I mount the shade to the wall surface, will I need those special anchors?  If so, what are they called?

Comment: @Katie There's sure to be wood somewhere around the window. I've made a guess based on experience where you might be likely to find it. It's preferable to screw into wood because that's more durable than drywall anchors, and if you succeed in finding the wood in the wall, then no drywall anchors are needed. A stud finder, or thin nail or drill bit, could help confirm where there's wood hidden behind the drywall. A question like "how to find studs around a window" might already have good answers, but if not, feel free to ask it!